# How to sum two columns from two different dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes `tmp` and `df`.

I would like to do the following sum

```
df.iloc[:,2] = tmp.iloc[:,2] + df.iloc[:,2]

tmp.iloc[:,2]

0         NaN
1         NaN
2         NaN
3      1693.0
4      3511.0
5         NaN
6         NaN
7      2285.0
8     63269.0
9         NaN
10    16637.0
11     4319.0
12     5361.0
13    32338.0
14    61578.0
15     9022.0
16     5648.0
17      190.0
18        NaN
19     3840.0
20    13217.0
21     8525.0
22     3725.0
23      552.0
24        NaN
25        NaN
26     3914.0
27     2328.0
28     1980.0
29    15436.0
30     5284.0
31      258.0
Name: (HOMEWORK, GAID), dtype: float64


df.iloc[:,2]

0          NaN
1          NaN
2          NaN
3       3403.0
4       6893.0
5          NaN
6          NaN
7       4605.0
8     126664.0
9          NaN
10     33022.0
11      8700.0
12     10796.0
13     64832.0
14    123594.0
15     18109.0
16     11377.0
17       394.0
18         NaN
19      7656.0
20     26441.0
21     16935.0
22      7572.0
23      1032.0
24         NaN
25         NaN
26      7824.0
27      4659.0
28      3884.0
29     30860.0
30     10562.0
31       510.0
Name: (HOMEWORK, GAID), dtype: float64
```

but if try

```
df.iloc[:,2] = tmp.iloc[:,2] + df.iloc[:,2]
```

I get the following:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert bool to numpy.ndarray
```

Comment: works on my system.

Comment: could you please show, how your tmp and df dataframe is looking?

Comment: I solved it just by renaming the columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum = df['tmp'] + df['df']  # a Series
# and
df['df'] = df['tmp'] + df['df']  # assigned to a column
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following line

```
df.iloc[:,2] = tmp.iloc[:,2].add(df.iloc[:,2],fill_value=0)
```